# iPhone X - Face ID IR programmable for whole body scan

Tags: ios, iphone-x, face-id

Is it possible to program Face ID, so you can get the depth IR map of a whole body instead of just the face?

Comment: TrueDepth camera can capture depth maps of whatever you point it at, not just faces.